# Integration of SQlite database (or any other suggestion) with Excel project in VB

Tags: excel, sqlite, vsto

I am very new to VB. I am working on an Excel-VB(2013) project in which I want to read data from another excel file, then compare some of its fields with existing data. So the question is about existing database which sits inside the application (no server, no online connection). 
I was wondering how can I add a sqlite DB file (or any other) into my project and then connect to that db and use it. I need help with some examples.

Thank you,

Comment: You can't "add" a database to an excel file, but you can turn an Excel file into a database using `VeryHidden` Worksheets.

Comment: Please pick *one* language: which one are you really using?  VB.net<>VBA<>VB6

Comment: If you're asking if you can embed a DB server into your project, then the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you all for quick reply and saving my time :). if I can't embedded sqlite into my project then using a hidden excel file as database is only way to go. Thanks @jbarker2160

Comment: Excel VBA *is not* VB6.  I see nothing here to give me confidence that a VB6 programmer should waste one second trying to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed it into any executable file, but you have to extract it to use it, usually in the temp folder. I use Reshacker to embed resources. Here's some old code. I'd use a adodb stream object these days rather than VB file operators.

```
Sub WriteFiles(DirectoryName, ResourceNo, FileName, FileNumber)
    frmSplash.Update FileNumber
    DoEvents
    Data = LoadResData(ResourceNo, "CUSTOM")
    fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open DirectoryName & "\" & FileName For Binary As #fileNum
    For x = 0 To UBound(Data)
        Put #fileNum, , CByte(Data(x))
        frmSplash.Label8 = FormatNumber(x / UBound(Data) * 100, 0) & "%"
        DoEvents
    Next
    Close fileNum
End Sub
```